# counts of grouped variables using dplyr

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I would like to create a dataframe with confidence intervals for proportions as a final result. I have introduced a variable (tp in my example) as a cut off value to calculate the proportions for. I would like to use the dplyr package to produce the final dataframe. 
Below is a simplified example:

```
library(dplyr)

my_names <- c("A","B")
dt <- data.frame(
  Z = sample(my_names,100,replace = TRUE),
  X = sample(1:10, replace = TRUE),
  Y = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE)
)  
  my.df <- dt%>%  
    mutate(tp = (X >8)* 1) %>% #multiply by one to convert into numeric
    group_by(Z, tp) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(prop.tp= n/sum(n)) %>%
    mutate(SE.tp = sqrt((prop.tp*(1-prop.tp))/n))%>%
    mutate(Lower_limit = prop.tp-1.96 * SE.tp)%>%
    mutate(Upper_limit = prop.tp+1.96 * SE.tp)

output:

Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
Groups: Z

  Z tp  n   prop.tp      SE.tp Lower_limit Upper_limit
1 A  0 33 0.6346154 0.08382498   0.4703184   0.7989123
2 A  1 19 0.3653846 0.11047236   0.1488588   0.5819104
3 B  0 27 0.5625000 0.09547033   0.3753782   0.7496218
4 B  1 21 0.4375000 0.10825318   0.2253238   0.6496762
```

However, I would like to calculate the Standard error and the CI:s using the total sample for the groups in column Z, not the splitted sample by the categorical variable tp.
So the total sample for A in my example should be n = 33 +19.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I get which group you want to compare with which here, but at any rate you have two grouping variables `tp = X > 8` and `Z`.
If you want to compare the rows with `X > 8` and `Z == "A"` to all rows with `X > 8` you can do it like this

```
merge(
    dt %>%
        group_by(X > 8) %>%
        summarize(n.X = n()),
    dt %>%
        group_by(X > 8, Z) %>%
        summarise(n.XZ = n()),
    by = "X > 8"
) %>%
    mutate(prop.XZ = n.XZ/n.X) %>%
    mutate(SE = sqrt((prop.XZ*(1-prop.XZ))/n.X))%>%
    mutate(Lower_limit = prop.XZ-1.96 * SE) %>%
    mutate(Upper_limit = prop.XZ+1.96 * SE)
```

> ```
>   X > 8 n.X Z n.XZ   prop.XZ         SE Lower_limit Upper_limit
> 1 FALSE  70 A   37 0.5285714 0.05966378   0.4116304   0.6455124
> 2 FALSE  70 B   33 0.4714286 0.05966378   0.3544876   0.5883696
> 3  TRUE  30 A   16 0.5333333 0.09108401   0.3548087   0.7118580
> 4  TRUE  30 B   14 0.4666667 0.09108401   0.2881420   0.6451913
> ```

If you want to turn the problem around and compare `X > 8` and `Z == "A"` to all rows with `Z == "A"` you can do it like this

```
merge(
    dt %>%
        group_by(Z) %>%
        summarize(n.Z = n()),
    dt %>%
        group_by(X > 8, Z) %>%
        summarise(n.XZ = n()),
    by = "Z"
) %>%
    mutate(prop.XZ = n.XZ/n.Z) %>%
    mutate(SE = sqrt((prop.XZ*(1-prop.XZ))/n.Z))%>%
    mutate(Lower_limit = prop.XZ-1.96 * SE) %>%
    mutate(Upper_limit = prop.XZ+1.96 * SE)
```

> ```
>   Z n.Z X > 8 n.XZ   prop.XZ         SE Lower_limit Upper_limit
> 1 A  53 FALSE   37 0.6981132 0.06305900   0.5745176   0.8217088
> 2 A  53  TRUE   16 0.3018868 0.06305900   0.1782912   0.4254824
> 3 B  47 FALSE   33 0.7021277 0.06670743   0.5713811   0.8328742
> 4 B  47  TRUE   14 0.2978723 0.06670743   0.1671258   0.4286189
> ```

It is a bit messy having to `merge` two separate groupings, but I don't know if it is possible to ungroup and re-group in the same statement. I am suprised though how difficult it seems to be to use groupings on two different levels (if you can call it that) and hope someone else can come up with a better solution.

Comment: close, I wanted to look at the proportions of A and B  ,where X >8 though...any ideas

Comment: Maybe the updated answer is what you want. To convert `tp` to numeric I suggest you use `as.integer` instead of multiply with 1, since it is easier to understand the purpose the operation then.